# Greenscreen recommendations

Tags: lighting, greenscreen, chromakey

I'm suffering with Greenscreen already several months. So I would appreciate any recommendations.
As you can see on the right side there is a spill on the head and arm.
My setup:

- 2 daylight bulbs (45 W CFL-Daylight) with umbrellas for subject 45 degree left and right.
- I also tried with and without 2 softboxes (45w CLF-Daylight) to light greenscreen. From what I see the greenscreen is not perfectly lit.
- Greenscreen is 2 meters behind the subject
- I key it in Final cut pro
- My camera is Sony 5100 f1.4, iso 100, 25 fps, shutter 1/50, 1080p

The main problem is that I don't know what I need to adjust. Is it the greenscreen than should be lit better or something else? Do I need more light or should it be dimmable?

Video with background:

Raw video with greenscreen:

Greenscreen image:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KZdV6WTNAfeuzzjkMhnL9iOdWnfFtKDw/view?usp=sharing

Greenscreen Problems image:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x0IBozaoU2gDFQAEjZrIu8tVWpi03fBz/view?usp=sharing

Greenscreen Problems image 2:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nh647wrV_kERR3y4bW6GSNcog8mG5yiA/view?usp=sharing

Keyed out image:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jSKZrsVYpdE3i1dxLuJRz81eD2_G_N3F/view?usp=sharing

Keyed out with sample color removal:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mTYnjIKM1dLBTb5gmfaI42EG-lcF5Fx0/view?usp=sharing

White/black image:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ptEZh4vhIYX9SRQgbEROqfkybv4TD7GD/view?usp=sharing

While/black with sample color removal:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dk9yFot721I2bY8lz90wJmZcp0evjLF5/view?usp=sharing

Also I tried adding 2 softboxes on the bottom. It helped with colors on the bottom of the screen but not with spill.

Image of my lamps setup:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wbaEKtbYzrkyiCIDsgt7fbNSsOBMZKGY/view?usp=sharing

I'm open for any suggestions. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice explanation of your problem.

I would simply move the two softboxes higher.

[image]

To minimize the falloff put the lights about the center of the framing of the camera. If your camera is targeting the green fabric at 1mt (I see the camera is pointing down a bit) put the lights at 1m.

Probably the softboxes have less power than the umbrellas. Try to add a stronger light on them. Just watch they do not overheat. Safety first.

---

I do not know if this would help, but If you do not use the window I would put the green screen there because it seems the room is longer in that direction, which will help you have a less green spill on you, and use a longer focal length.

Comment: Thanks you for advice. Actually it's working for me right now but the idea with moving greenscreen to the window is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Bit overwhelmed with all the links, but from an initial look my first reaction is that you need more light on the screen, and while you're at it, a backlight on your subject would help things along too.

From the fringing it looks like you need to turn up the gain of your key. If your key effect doesn't have a screen gain control, you can achieve the same result by increasing the saturation of the screen colour with another effect applied before the key effect. To remove the fringe in the existing footage you could apply a matte choker effect, and to remove the green-ness a de-spill effect. I'm not sure what these are called in FCP.

Comment: I tried to be as informative as possible :) Thanks I will try your suggestions.